# Does GCC support multiple target architectures?

Tags: gcc, cpu-architecture

Is it possible to compile a single `gcc` (frontend) binary which supports multiple target architectures, which I can select in the command-line, like this:

```
$ gcc --architecture=linux-i386 ...
$ gcc --architecture=freebsd-arm ...
$ gcc --architecture=darwin-amd64 ...
```

I know that it's possible build gcc as a cross-compiler, but is it possible to select the target architecture using a command-line flag, without writing a wrapper script which starts different `gcc` binaries for each architecture?

For i386 and amd64 `-m32` and `-m64` seem to do the trick, but how do I select ARM etc.? Please note that `-march=` looked useless to me, I couldn't make it change from i386 to amd64.

Comment: Usually you would use a cross compiler if you want to switch to ARM. Is there any particular reason you want this as a compiler flag and not as an alias?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer is "no", you can't. There are some flavors of cross compilers, but for one binary to be able to support a bunch of targets, it would require the tool to be very bulky in size and requirement for system headers.

Comment: `clang` does it just fine, and there is a (very) long-term goal for gcc to do it as well...

Comment: @MarcGlisse where to read about this goal of gcc, its status etc? Even google doesn't help me to find it.

Comment: AFAIK, there are just a few comments now and then, preferring struct members to global variables, things like that, but no one is actively working towards that goal. That's because it is not a priority, but if someone were to contribute patches in this direction, I am sure they would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Function multi-versioning is there https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning, including automatic dispatching;

Still versioning is manual; automatic multi-versioning for different architectures is not implemented; here's feature request for it https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78464

Comment: That's about different levels of ISA extensions within one target.  The question is asking about a GCC equivalent for `clang -c -target mips foo.c` or whatever, which Just Works for x86-64 clang on your x86-64 desktop

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. It looks like this doesn't make it possible to target ARM and amd64 in the same binary (as I wrote it in the question).